# MySQL check if value exist  in row, separated by minus

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with ProductIDs and associated Accessories Ids separated by minus.

```
 ProductId    Accessories
 1            1-2-3-
 2            3-4-
 3            1-2-3-
 4            2-3-
```

How can I get ProductIds where Accessories Id = 2

I tried this query but it is not working correct

```
SELECT *
FROM `products`
WHERE '-' + Accessories + '-' LIKE '%-2-%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Database can't be changed.

Comment: NO! NO! NO! normalize your database and create an accessories table... otherwise you're crippling yourself with all manner of problems (including this one)

Comment: @MarkBaker - Sometimes developers operate under unreasonable rules. _"Database can't be changed."_ -- OP seems aware of how broken this is.

Comment: I don't see anything in this post that demonstrates he knows it's bad practise

Comment: @MarkBaker - It is bad practise but not mine I'm just adding new functionality to existing database.

Comment: + is the addition operator, not concatenation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you absolutely have to do this incredibly bad practise that will complicate your coding life until the day you retire:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM products 
 WHERE CONCAT('-',Accessories) LIKE '%-2-%' 
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This won't work for ProductId 4, or any product where 2 is the first accessory id

Comment: @Brian, please explain why not... I stand by to be educated, because that's the whole point of the CONCAT

Comment: Thank you works great ! Maybe you know why my version it is not working, this seams to be the same.

Comment: Although this will work, it prevents any use of indexes on the field accessories.

Comment: @Cassy: Assuming you're referring to the CONCAT, the leading wild card on the LIKE would kill any chance of using indexes anyhow.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli: That's what I mean. Forgot about the wildcard though.

Comment: Oh god, may I never see a database with a multi-valued yet well-indexed Accessories column.

Comment: @devsoft - Your version doesn't work because + is the numeric addition operator, not a concatenation operator

Answer (score 2):

Although the following solution also has problems with using an index, I wanted to add it for completeness:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `products` 
 WHERE find_in_set('2', replace(`accessories`, '-', ','))
 LIMIT 0, 30;
```

**Explanation:**

`replace(accessories, '-', ',')` turns the accessories lists into a comma separated list, for example `1-2-3-` will be converted to `1,2,3,`

`find_in_set(value, set)` can then be used to see if a `value` is contained in `set`.

As I said earlier, no index can be used, but the performance should be measured on the live data set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost had it. Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Accessories LIKE '%-2-%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: This won't match when 2 is the first item in the list. You need to include a leading dash on the Accessories column.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli - Good point. Hats off to Mark Baker for catching that edge case.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that those values ALWAYS have a trailing dash, then you've got a few cases to cover:

1) single value: `... WHERE Accessories = CONCAT($value, '-')`
2) value at start:  `... WHERE Accessories LIKE '$value-%'`
3) value in the middle: `... WHERE Accessories LIKE '%-$value-%'`
4) value at the end: `... WHERE Accessories LIKE '-$value-$'`

which'd end up being this in the full(er) SQL:

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE 
    (Accessories = CONCAT($value, '-')) OR             // single
    (Accessories LIKE CONCAT($value, '-%')) OR         // start
    (Accessories LIKE CONCAT('%-', $value, '-%')) OR   // middle
    (Accessories LIKE CONCAT('%-', $value, '-'))       // end
```